# Reading between certain characters in excel cell string

Tags: vba, excel-formula

New working on VBA with excel. Learning on my own and happy this community exist.

I am working on picking information from a string within a cell in excel.

Example:
cell value: Make.Model.Issuer

I'm trying to read any set of characters using the "." as limits.
read from right till "."
read between "."
read from left till "."

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: You can use split to do this pretty easily, or instr with left right and mid.

Comment: That was fast. Thank you so much. In that example make model and issuer will have different lengths and cant use a fixed length to read.

Comment: So you want to retrieve 3 words in this case?

Comment: yes. whatever length of a string in between specific characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will generate an array with the picked words:

```
Dim s As String
Dim a As Variant
   
s = "Make.Model.Issuer"
a = Split(s, ".")
MsgBox a(0) & "   " & a(1) & "   " & a(2)
```

Comment: Thank you both. I will play with those two options. This solves it for me. I appreciate you all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the extracted strings so I'm going to place them in cells.

This will iterate down column A and place the split string into as many columns as it needs to in the same row.

```
    Dim strarr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim j As Long
    With Sheet1 'Change as needed
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Change the 1 to whatever your column is
        For i = 1 To lr
            strarr = Split(.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".") 'Change the 1 to whatever your column is
            For j = LBound(strarr) To UBound(strarr)
                .Cells(i, 1).Offset(, j + 1).Value = strarr(j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you both. I will play with those two options. This solves it for me. I appreciate you all.